# Which one are the best TIPS to make a logo for web?

Tags: website-design, logo, interface-design

i need to make a logo for a development company,and the logo will be displayed in screen most of the time, so i will like to know every tips to make the logo more responsive and totally functional. If you have a video or any source where to find advice it will be pretty nice.

Answer (score 2):

Even though your logo will appear onscreen most of time, I would still recommend designing it in vector format with Adobe Illustrator. YOU NEVER KNOW WHEN THEY'LL NEED IT FOR PRINT. Then, you can create a variety of sizes in bitmap form for your client so they can choose the appropriate size.  Including pngs too so they can use it over a color background. If you just give them one file as a jpeg, they could unwittingly use it at a much larger size and you'll be disappointed with the degradation that occurs. Hope this helps,
Ellen